# Can I use gsub to recursively replace all fieldnames with another field?

Tags: logstash

After changing my mapping in ElasticSearch to more definitively type the data I am inputting into the system, I have unwittingly made my new variables a nested object.  Upon thinking about it more, I actually like the idea of those fields being nested objects because that way I can explicitly know if that `src_port` statistic is from netflow or from the ASA logs, as an example.

I'd like to use a `mutate` (gsub, perhaps?) to cause all of my fieldnames for a given type to be renamed to `newtype.fieldname`.  I see that there is `gsub` which uses a regexp, and rename which takes the literal field name, but I would like to prevent having 30 distinct gsub/rename statements when I will be replacing all of the fields in that type with the "newtype" prefix.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example for your reference.

```
input {
    stdin{
            type => 'netflow'
    }
}

filter {
    mutate {
            add_field => {"%{type}.message" => "%{message}"}
            remove_field => ["message"]
    }
}

output {
    stdout{
            codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

In this example I have change the `message` field name to `type.message`, then delete the origin `message` field. I think you can use this sample to do what you want.

Hope this can help you.

**I have updated my answer!**

Use the ruby plugin to do what you want!
Please notice that elasticsearch uses `@timestamp` field to do index, so I recommend do not change the field name.

```
input {
    stdin{
        type => 'netflow'
    }
}

filter {
    ruby {
        code => "
            data = event.clone.to_hash;
            type = event['type']
            data.each do |k,v|
                if k != '@timestamp'
                    newFieldName = type +'.'+ k
                    event[newFieldName] = v
                    event.remove(k)
                end
            end
        "
    }
}

output {
    stdout{
        codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Ben and thanks for your response! My question was more of the form "can I iterate through all field names with one mutate? e.g. instead of %{type}.message, I'd like to add the field netflow.%{fieldname}.  Is this possible?

Comment: I have update my answer! If you like it, please accept it as the answer. Thank you and have a nice day :)

Comment: The code you provided does exactly what I needed!  Thank you.